# Core Service - WebDavUrl null for Component

Tags: 2011, core-service

When I read a component's WebDavUrl via PageData using the Core Service its returning "null"?

```
var page = (PageData)client.Read("tcm:71-122971-64", new ReadOptions());                
Console.WriteLine(page.ComponentPresentations[0].Component.WebDavUrl);
```

Is there a different way to get to the WebDavUrl?

Answer (score 6):

`WebDavUrl`s of linked items are not read unless you are reading it with correct `LoadFlags`, like:

```
var page = (PageData)client.Read("tcm:71-122971-64", new ReadOptions{LoadFlags = LoadFlags.WebDavUrls});
```

Comment: Just spotted that when you answered! Gotta wait 10 minutes before I can accept though!

Comment: Intrigued - what's wrong with the use of "as" when casting then Dominic?

Comment: To me, a cast is always preferred over using the `as` keyword, since the latter will not throw an exception when the cast is invalid. But if you will always check if your object returned is not null, then you can just as well use the `as` keyword.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/08/what-s-the-difference-between-as-and-cast-operators.aspx

Comment: I see Bart and David have already provided good input. For the full discussion - rants and all... see http://meta.tridion.stackexchange.com/q/168/129 :-)